# How are answers accepted when a user doesn't exist any more?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have noticed some questions being edited post-merger where the OP doesn't link to a profile. I guess this is fallout from old UXE questions migrating when there isn't a user account for them here at UXSE.

So I wonder how answers will be accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OP didn't accept an answer on UXExchange, it's unlikely they would have come over here and eventually accepted one. I think that's okay -- it's not necessary for every question to have an accepted answer.

We should continue voting on answers so the best ones float to the top.